# Prove that the equation has exactly n real roots

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials

If $0<a_1<a_2<...<a_n$, show that the following equation has exactly n real roots: $$\frac{a_1}{a_1-x}+ \frac{a_2}{a_2-x}+...+ \frac{a_n}{a_n-x}=2015$$

Comment: i don't think the condition $a_1 \lt a_2 \lt a_3 \cdots \lt a_n$ is necessary. Only $a_i \gt 0$ $\forall$ $i \in \mathbb{R}$ will suffice

Comment: Yeah... It's a set of positive numbers... And, the function is symmetrical... So, we can always assume an ordering...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{a_k - x} - 2015$$

Then,

$$f'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{(a_k - x)^2}$$

Notice that $f$ is then increasing over each interval of its domain.

Now apply IVT $n$ times.

Comment: How do you know there exist $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$ for each interval?

Comment: @cr001: $\lim_{x \to a_k ^+ } f < 0 < \lim_{x \to a_{k+1}^-} f$

Answer (score 3):

Let $z$ be a complex root. Then its conjugate $\bar{z}$ is also a root. so

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i}{a_i-z}=2015 \tag{1}$$ and

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i}{a_i-\bar{z}}=2015 \tag{2}$$  subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$ we get

$$(z-\bar{z})\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i}{(a_i-Re(z))^2+|z|^2-(Re(z))^2}=0$$

which is possible only if $$z=\bar{z}$$ so Real roots

Comment: Yeah. That proves the inexistance of imaginary roots. But, that's not what I need. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There are a total of $n$ roots, since we are basically dealing (after clearing denominators) with a polynomial of degree $n$. So the argument above shows there are, counting multiplicity, $n$ real roots. That almost completes things, the only thing remaining is to check there are no multiple roots.

Comment: How can we check that? Don't you think your method is perhaps more straightforward? @André Nicolas

Comment: @SayantanSantra If $x$ a multiple root of a polynomial $P$, it is a root of its derivative. Now it's enough to rewrite the equation as a polynom, and take the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $f(x)$ be the function on the left. Wherever $f(x)$ is defined, we have $f'(x)\gt 0$. So in any interval in which $f(x)$ is defined, it is increasing.

Now show that $f(x)=2015$ has exactly one root between any two $a_i$, and also one root less than $a_1$, and no root greater than $a_n$. The Intermediate Value Theorem may be useful.

Comment: Actually, I found this on a question set. I haven't completed the course yet. So, can you please tell me where should I look for this kind of a problem. Maybe suggest a book.

Comment: It is the kind of problem that is on the slightly theoretical side of a standard calculus course. There may also be a more algebraic solution, but the calculus approach is the one that springs first to mind,

Comment: I can visualize what you're saying but don't have the mathematical tools to write it down. Maybe I should go through the book once and search for similar problems. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Let us think about the function between say $a_2$ and $a_3$. When $x$ is extremely close to $a_2$ but a bit above $a_2$, the function value is huge positive. As we travel to the right towards $a_3$ the function is steadily decreasing, When $x$ is very close to $a_3$, the function value is very negative, So somewhere between $a_2$ and $a_3$, it is exactly $2015$, or any other number you want. (More)

Comment: Hmm... I think I get it. It'd be easier for me if I take $f(x)-2015$ and show that it achieves zero.

Comment: (More) A suggestion: Let $n=3$, say. Pick $a_1,a_2,a_3$ however you like, say $1$, $2$, and $5$. Use a graphing program (Wolfram Alpha works) to graph the curve $y=f(x)$. You will *see* the kind of behaviour I described.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong. I think we have to prove it kinda cuts the axis, thus achieving zero.

Comment: Sort of. I would rather think of it as $f(x)$ cutting the horizontal line $y=2015$.

Comment: Yeah. I was talking about $f(x)-2015$. You're right.